# Using partially matching functions as delegates?

Tags: c#, delegates

Lets say I have:

```
static void Foo(string s, int i){//some implementation}
static void Bar(string s){//some other implementation}
delegate void Del(string s);
```

obviously, it is possible to go:

```
Del d = Bar
```

but is it possible to do something like:

```
Del d2 = Foo(7); //just takes in string s as the only parameter;
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to redefine some of the parameters so that the leftover parameters match the signature of the delegate.

Is this possible without having to define an intermediate method like this:

```
static void IntermediateMethod(string s){ return Foo(s, 7);}
```

`

Comment: So so you want a delegate to magically be assignable to anything and guess what it needs? the answer is no, you cant even call `Foo(7)` or `Foo("asdf")` on the best of days anyway delegate or not. Whats the use case here, so we can better understand why you want this and what you want

Comment: I don't want it to magically happen, I was wondering if there was some sort of system for defining which parameters go where, maybe using the method embedded in some sort of lambda expression. 

I don't really have a use case, I'm just curious about the nitty-gritty parts of C#.

Comment: Ah Sorry, I just realized I made a mistake. I've edited the last line.

Comment: Computer still says no, you cant pump differing signatures into a delegate

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the closest I can get to what I wanted.

```
Del d2 = delegate(string s){Foo(s,7);};
```

This basically achieves my goal since the method is anonymous and you don't need an intermediate method.

Comment: Does this even compile?  `Del` still expects 1 argument.

Comment: Should compile now. Sorry, I've not got VS open on this computer atm so I'm just winging it.

Comment: `(string s){Foo(s,7);}` _is_ an intermediate method.